# How to automatically attribute ID to the class objects in c++

Tags: c++, oop, vector

I'm beginner in object-oriented programming. As the learning project I've decided to create a little program to manage a company. How to count created objects? I've read about it but I don't understand it. I'd like to request for show me how should I do it using as an example my code:

```
class Employee
{
public:
    std::string name;
    int age;
    static int id;

    Employee::Employee()
    {
        id++;
    }
};

int Employee::id = 0;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<Employee>& v)
{
    out << "[";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        out << "ID: " << v[i].id <<  " Name: " << v[i].name << " age: " << v[i].age;
        if (i != v.size() - 1)
            out << ", ";
    }
    out << "]";

    return out;
}

Employee generate_random_employee(Employee obj)
{
    std::vector<std::string> male_names = {"Donald", "Piotr", "James", "Tiny", "Ricky"};
    std::vector<std::string> female_names = {"Diana", "Joelle", "Sue", "Karolina"};
    std::vector<std::string> lastnames = {"Lester", "Pound", "Park", "Ennis", "Duck",
                                        "Tusk", "Disney", "Jurassic", "Looney-Warde" };

    int sex = (rand() % 2) + 0;

    if (sex == 1)
    {
        obj.name = male_names[(rand() % (male_names.size() - 1)) + 0];
    }
    else
    {
        obj.name = female_names[(rand() % (female_names.size() - 1)) + 0];
    }

    obj.name += " " + lastnames[(rand() % (lastnames.size() - 1)) + 0];
    obj.age = (rand() % 24) + 25;

    return obj;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    std::vector<Employee> employees;
    Employee some_new_employee;

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        some_new_employee = generate_random_employee(some_new_employee); //randomly generate a new employee. It is Employee type function
        employees.push_back(some_new_employee);
    }

    std::cout << employees << std::endl;
}
```

at the moment the program constantly attribute 1 as the ID for all objects

Comment: your code does not compile ... missing function  "generate_random_employee()"

Comment: I've wanted to show the program looks. I didn't realize that u need this function to help me. I've added it. Sorry

Comment: Thanks ... your function is quite reasonable.  It turns out the question tolerates the employees not being random, so my solution below ignores all but the ID.

Comment: I like your operator>>() handling a vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a unique id for each employee try:

```
class Employee
{
public:
   std::string name;
   int age;
   int id;

   static int ID;

   Employee()
      {
         id = ID++;
      }
};

int Employee::ID = 0;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<Employee>& v)
{
   // ...
   return out;
}
```

Main (simplified)

```
   std::vector<Employee> employees;

   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   {
      Employee e;
      employees.push_back(e);
   }

   std::cout << employees << std::endl;
```

output:

```
[ID: 0 Name:  age: 0, ID: 1 Name:  age: 0, ID: 2 Name:  age: 0, ID: 3 Name:  age: 0]
```

---

Key idea:  each instance of the object requires a *unique* id.  A static is just the opposite ... a common value for all instances.

The ctor sets its own id AND increments the static ID.

Note that ID represents how many have been contructed, but not how many might be existing (consider destructors, temps, copies, etc).

Comment: I've got it but the code still does not work properly. I've compiled yours and it does not work too. For all objects it attribute 0 as the ID.

Comment: my apologies ... I will re-cut-paste.

Comment: ok, my bad. I didn't place the constructor `Employee e` inside the loop. Thank you

Comment: what if I will want to place it into `swtich () case`? I cannot create a new variable inside it, can I?

Comment: sounds like a new question .. switch cases are surprisingly un-restrictive about such things.  Sorry, I can't seem to guess what you are thinking about, Let me know if you write a new question.

Answer (score 2):

`generate_random_employee(some_new_employee);
employees.push_back(some_new_employee);`

None of those lines calls the constructor.

You should overload the assignment operator or the copy constructor to also increase the count.

And you can't have a static id... Static means that all your instances will have the same id...

You want a satic counter and use it to assign the id on construction.

Comment: thanks, your answer helps me to understand the issue